# How to migrate Zeppelin notebooks to Azure Databricks

Tags: apache-zeppelin, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm working on a project of migrating zeppelin notebooks to Azure Databricks, I haven't find any documentation on the same.
Any guidance on that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no proven tool to migrate/convert zeppelin notebook to databricks notebook.
Both notebooks are json format but follow different formats.

Ipython(databricks) : https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I could find github repo https://github.com/rdblue/jupyter-zeppelin that addresses your issue, but it is not updated recently so not sure if it will work on latest versions.

You can give a try and modify the code if required.